# Order hql results by specific property value

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I have a domain that contains a property called 'Status'.
This property can contain 'A','I','P','Pv','R'.

I have the following query:

```
def list = Deal.findAll('from Deal as d')
```

How can I order the results so that rows with status of 'P' are always returned at the top of the result set? (I don't care in what order they come after that).

Comment: Would it be a problem to fetch all `where d.property == 'P'`, and then all the others `ordered by d.property`, and merge them on the client side? For example: `def list = Deal.findAll('from Deal as d where d.prop == "P"'); list.addAll(Deal.findAll('from Deal as d where d.prop <> "P" order by d.prop))` (Btw this is meta-syntax. Adjust to your needs.)

Comment: def list = Deal.findAll('from Deal as d order by (d.status=='P')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do what you want? Normally I'd test it before answering but I don't have an easy way to do that atm.

```
def list = Deal.findAll('''from Deal as d order by case d.property when 'P' then 0 else 1 end''')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort method with a comparator:

```
def list = Deal.findAll('from Deal as d').sort({a,b-> (a.status== 'P' && b.status != 'P') ? 0 : 1 })
```

Comment: Creating a map and casting to `Comparator` is not necessary.  You can simply pass the closure `{a,b-> (a.status== 'P' && b.status != 'P') ? 0 : 1 }` to the `sort()` method.